# Bootstrap container divs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys using bootstrap and struggling to understand how to get a my main div box to have other divs inside of it

For example i am trying to make this:

[image]

This big box is just a div.

What i got so far:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="MainBox">
      <div class="Leftbox">
        <h3>Box</h3>
        <div class="btn-group-vertical">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive">P</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-responsive">B</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-responsive">L</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-responsive">R</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-responsive">T</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-responsive">F</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="CentreBox">     
    </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not so sure how to do the boxes on the right hand side , i have tried different methods but it mucks up the whole div. Any help would be great. Thanks xx

Comment: If you're using bootstrap then look into columns. They can separate the page out for you https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: Doesn't look like you're utilizing the responsive grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to look into Bootstraps grid system, as suggested by @Sringland in his comments, found here: [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

The grid system creates 12 columns on any screen size (from xtra small - large), and can be defined as a class by col-(screensize)-(span).  For example - if you want 12 columns spanning a large sized screen add the class: `col-lg-12` to your div.

These columns are "embeddable", and will create a new 12-column layout inside one another.  So if you want to split up an 8 column layout into two equal sized containers within it, it would like like this:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
  <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
</div>
```

So remember, each time you "open" a column regardless of its size, that container will have another 12 columns to work with.

After all this is said, your layout will look something like this:

```
<div class="row height-500px">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 border height-500px">
      <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 border height-500px">
      <!-- CONTENT GOES HERE -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 height-500px">
      <div class="col-md-12 height-125px border">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 height-125px border">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 height-125px border">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 height-125px border">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/UQuUDPREqn) to see it in action.  *Please see the bootply for a better understanding of the height classes and border classes.  I created these simply to represent your layout.*

Now, gutters (the space between the columns) are not working as intended, and I hope someone help there.  But, hopefully this will be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Thats great, i will defo look into, thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

Jus try using bootstrap grid system. I used buttons for the right column, but you can use whatever you need.

```
<div class="container MainBox border-on">
      <div class="col-md-2 left border-on">
        <h3>Box</h3>
        <div class="btn-group-vertical">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive">P</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-responsive">B</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-responsive">L</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-responsive">R</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-responsive">T</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-responsive">F</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 CentreBox border-on"> 
    <h3>
    center    
    </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 right border-on">
        <h3>
            right
        </h3>  
        <div class="col-md-12">
            One
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Two
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Three
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Four
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: On the right hand side they have to be 4 sepreate divs as they are going to have 4 images in them, thats the problem

Comment: just keep using the grid system the same way.changes posted on my previous post.